# No duplicate username

Tags: python, list, random

```
                  data=[] 
                  generate = random.randrange(100,1000)
                  genusername=newName[0]+newSurname[0:3]+str(generate)
                  print("Generated username : ", genusername)
                  available=True
                  while(available):
                    count=0
                    while (count<len(data)):
                      avail = data[count][5]
                      if(genusername==avail):
                        generate = random.randrange(100,1000)
                        genusername=newName[0]+newSurname[0:3]+str(generate)
                        print("Generated username again : ", genusername)   
                        count=0
                      else:
                        count+=1
                    available=False
```

it says Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 109, in 
avail = data[count][5]
IndexError: string index out of range
I'm trying to generate multiple usernames without a duplicate but not working how do I fix this error?

Comment: Please provide a more complete example. The code should not enter the `while (count<len(data)):` loop because `len(data)` is 0.

Answer (score 0):

Why not do something easier?

1. Initialize your arrays, variables
2. Generate a surname
3. Generate a family name
4. Generate a random number
5. Combine 2 + 3 + 4

Using this method, you will always have a unique identifier.

If you want to run a check, you will have to dump all of these to a file or big array, and you can use a simple search to verify they're not duplicates.